# Сложности решения задачи ''Страницы книги''

Tags: python

На каждой странице книги напечатано ровно k строк: на первой странице находятся строки с 1 по k, на второй — c k+1 по 2k и т.д. Определите, на какой странице находится строка номер n и какой по счёту будет эта строка на странице.

Даны натуральные числа k и n, каждое в отдельной строке. Программа должна считать их и вывести два числа: номер страницы и номер строки на странице.
В задаче нельзя использовать массивы и условия.
Вот мой код

```
    k = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    a = n//k
    b = n%k
    print(a, b)
```

Вводные данные: 50 100

Но получается, так что моя программа не учитывет последнюю 50 строку и переводит на новою страницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но получается, так что моя программа не учитывет последнюю 50 строку и переводит на новою страницу.

Это логично, ведь 99//50 = 1, а 100//50 = 2. Чтобы решить эту проблему, вы можете прибегнуть к преобразованию:

```py
k = int(input())
n = int(input())
a = (n-1) // k + 1 # если нумерация страниц с 1. Если нумерация с 0, то +1 нужно убрать
b = (n-1) % k + 1
print(a, b)
```

Comment: Непонятно... Разве не должен быть ответ `2 50` (страница № 2, строка № 50), для входных данных `50 100`? Первая страница содержит строки 1 - 50, вторая страница строки 51 - 100.

Comment: @MiniMax да, вы правы, на крайних пределах были проблемы. Исправил код

Comment: Чтобы работало, как я описал в предыдущем комментарии, можно сделать вот так: `print(a, b if b != 0 else k)` при `b = n % k`. При вводных данных `50 1000` ответ будет `20 50` - страница № 20, строка № 50.

Comment: @MiniMax исправленный ответ именно такой результат и даёт

Answer (score 0):

```
k=int(input())
n=int(input())
st=-((-n)//k)
stroka=n-k*(st-1)
print(st,stroka)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]